# Conversion of Date Format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-formatting

I want to know if it is possible to convert date format in SQL. e.g. from `27-jan-2016` to only `27-jan`.

Comment: Check the documentation for `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` functions.

Comment: `select to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon') from dual;` this is a simple example how you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if it is possible to convert date format in sql. e.g. from 27-jan-2016 to only 27-jan

Yes. You need to use **TO_CHAR** to display the **DATE** in your **desired format**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon', 'nls_date_language=english') dt_format FROM dual;

DT_FOR
------
27-jan
```

Comment: Can i use this ``to_char`` statement inside case statement in sql?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  select to_date(column,'dd-mon') from table
```